# Finding which elements in an array do not exist for a field value in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection users as follows:

```js
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51780f796ec4051a536015cf"), "userId" : "John" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51780f796ec4051a536015d0"), "userId" : "Sam" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51780f796ec4051a536015d1"), "userId" : "John1" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51780f796ec4051a536015d2"), "userId" : "john2" }
```

Now I am trying to write a code which can provides suggestions of a userId to user in case id provided by user already exists in DB. In same routine I just append values from 1 to 5 to the for example in case user have selected userId to be John, suggested user name array that needs to be checked for Id in database will look like this

```js
[John,John1,John2,John3,John4,John5].
```

Now I just want to execute it against Db and to find out which of the suggested values do not exist in DB. So instead of selecting any document, I want to select values within suggested array which do not exist for users collection.

Any pointers are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your general approach here is you want to find the "distinct" values for the "userId's" that already exist in your collection. You then compare these to your input selection to see the difference.

```js
var test = ["John","John1","John2","John3","John4","John5"];

var res = db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "userId": { "$in": test } }},
    { "$group": { "_id": "$userId" }}
]).toArray();

res.map(function(x){ return x._id });

test.filter(function(x){ return res.indexOf(x) == -1 })
```

The end result of this is the userId's that do not match in your initial input:

```js
[ "John2", "John3", "John4", "John5" ]
```

The main operator there is [**`$in`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) which takes an array as the argument and compares those values against the specified field. The [`.aggregate()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) method is the best approach, there is a shorthand mapReduce wrapper in the [`.distinct()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/) method which directly produces just the values in the array, removing the call to a function like `.map()` to strip out the values for a given key:

```js
var res = db.collection.distinct("userId",{ "userId": { "$in": test } })
```

It should run notably slower though, especially on large collections.

Also do not forget to index your "userId" and likely you want this to be "unique" anyway so you really just want the **`$match`** or [`.find()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) result:

```js
var res = db.collection.find({ "$in": test }).toArray()
```